# Gerrit repo - Files should be pointers

Tags: git, gerrit

I'm contributing to a Gerrit repository and just did a clone of the repo on a new Windows machine and got this message:

> Encountered 7 file(s) that should have been pointers, but weren't:

Got a bit confused, so I tried the exact same clone command (*it includes fetching a commit-msg hook into /.git/hooks*) on my linux machine, and I got no such message. I've come to understand it relates to LFS, but I don't really understand how that works or what to do about it.

Since these files show up as unstaged straight from the fresh clone command, I first tried to just commit them and try pushing them to my "change"/commit/branch on Gerrit, but I'm faced with this error:

```
Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
$ git config lfs.https://gerrit.xxxx.xxx/MyRepo.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
batch request: Server configuration error: LFS auth over SSH is not properly configured.: exit status 1
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://xxxxx@gerrit.xxxx.xxx:yyyyy/MyRepo'
```

Since this isn't just my own private repo, I really want to be sure about what to do with this to avoid messing something up.